# I want to create a unique id behind my URL and echo a page on it how to do this?

Tags: php

I have a form and the URL is for example: `www.site.com/index.php`. But when I click the form button I want it to create a link like this `www.site.com/index.php?1wejf23912` and then echo a page on it where you can put a username and password. How to do this and get the input from that page on the example page like `www.site.com/index.php`.

Thanks for the help.

```php
<?php
    require 'includes/header.php';
?>

<main>
    <form action="includes/create-page.inc.php">
        <button type="submit" name="create-submit" id="create-submit">Create Link
            With Page</button>
    </form>

    <div class="show-input">
        <a href="new-link">This is your link: <?php echo $newLink; ?></a>
        ...input from created page
        <button type="submit" name="delete-url" id="delete-url">Delete New URL</button>
    </div>
</main>

<?php
    require 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder **c** and you are going to add this.

```
<?php
        function randomURL() {
            $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
            $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
            $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
                $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
                $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
            }
            return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
        }
        $rpass = randomURL();
        echo "<h2>You link is <a target='_blank' href='/c/". $rpass. "'>". $_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"]. "://". $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]. "/c/";
        echo $rpass;
        echo "</a></h2>";
        $myfile = fopen("../c/". $rpass .".php", "w") or die("Unable to create file!");
        $txt = "Your text or variable or php code" ."\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Use .htaccess in the **c** folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: I made my question more specific can you help me? Thanks for the explaining before.

Comment: I thought you knew php a bit, but anyways I will answer with more detail.

Comment: I thought you knew php a bit, but anyways I will answer with more detail a bit later because I need to do some experiments.

Comment: Ok PHPRookie, be happy.

Comment: Do you want any help with error pages like 404, 403 etc. The question is toooo complicated. I don't have enough time. Sorry, Sorry, Sorry, Sorry

Comment: I will respond later

Comment: No problem I appreciate your help very much. I'm a quick learner I have allready made a login system with some help from a php developer. But I dont know how to make this its kind of complicated. Because I want to view the live input on the index.php page in a div that is visual when you create a link.